# What's the syntax for abstract methods?

Tags: f#

I've successfully defined and used interfaces with functions that only take one parameter, like the one below.

```
type IAnimal =
    abstract member Eat : Food -> unit
```

But I can't figure out how to define an abstract member with multiple parameters, like this.

```
    abstract member Feel : (Smell, Taste) -> unit
```

What's the syntax for abstract members? How do you define an abstract member with multiple parameters?

Comment: `Smell -> Taste -> unit`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have interface easily accessed also in other .NET languages then you can define multiple parameters as tuple, just like you tried, like:

```
abstract member Feel : smell : Smell * taste : Taste -> unit
```